# CSS transition doesn't work properly when appending dynamically class

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-transitions

I write a CSS for my own main div:

```
.main {
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: whitesmoke;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: gray;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: height 1s ease-in;
}

.visible {
  height: 96%;
}
```

When some state changes in my own program I would trigger .visible CSS class.
But it not working.

Check my React section:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import styles from "../../sass/DownModal.module.scss";
import { ConfigContext } from "../../context/config";
import { EnumPageFrom } from "../../business/Icon";

function Index({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const { setActiveMenu, setBackground, activeMenu } =
    useContext(ConfigContext);
  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles.main} ${
        activeMenu == EnumPageFrom.MenuAdd && styles.visible
      }`}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Every stuff are working properly except CSS (.visible) class!

Why and How can I fit it?

Edit

```
.visible {
  height: 96%;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0%;
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: whitesmoke;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: gray;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: height 4s;
}


<div
      className={`${styles.main} ${
        activeMenu == EnumPageFrom.MenuAdd ? styles.visible : styles.hidden
      }`}
    >
      {children}
```

I breaking a snipped into some sections but transition still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential issues that could be causing the .visible class not to be applied as expected:

1. Make sure that the activeMenu variable is being set correctly and
   that the value of activeMenu is what you expect it to be when you
   want the .visible class to be applied. You can check this by adding
   a console log to print out the value of activeMenu at different
   points in your code.
2. Make sure that the styles object in your React component contains
   the correct class names for the .main and .visible classes. You can
   check this by inspecting the styles object in your debugger or by
   adding a console log to print out the object.
3. Make sure that the .visible class is being defined correctly in your
   CSS. Make sure that the height property is set to a value that is
   greater than 0, and make sure that the transition property is set
   correctly. You can try adding a different property (such as color or
   font-size) to the .visible class and see if it is applied as
   expected to help narrow down the issue.

Comment: please check edit section